# (OpenCV) java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError проблема Mat Android

Tags: android, исключения, изображения, opencv

Никак не могу получить изображение из ресурсов или памяти, выдает `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`,

```
Mat m = null;
    try {
        m = Utils.loadResource(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.battery_low, Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(m.cols(), m.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(m, bm);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Аналогично и при конвертации `Bitmap` в `Mat`

```
matSelectedImage = new Mat(selectedImage.getHeight(), selectedImage.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(0, 0, 0));
Utils.bitmapToMat(selectedImage, matSelectedImage);
```

Думаю, что сама библиотека подключена корректно, шаблон кода для получения изображения с камеры работает корректно. Может есть другие способы, как положить изображение в `Mat` контейнер?

Answer (score 1):

Окей, всё оказалось очень тупо. В скачанных с офф сайта библиотеках, в папке x86 он искал libopencv_java320.so, а он был назван libopencv_java3.so, переименование файла исправило ситуацию.